# How to download files with close lid of laptop?

Tags: laptop, download, bittorrent

I want to download any file (via torrent or download manager) and I  want to close my laptop lid too. As I know, it is not possible but is there any way to do this that  downloading will be continue even after closing the lid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your download stops isn't because you closed the lid, but because closing the lid is causing your laptop to enter sleep mode.

You need to go into control panel in Windows, or System Preferences in OS X and change that behavior.

Comment: I tried this but even after changing the settings downloading stops.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I tried this but its not working for me. I am using windows 8. Whenever I close the lid, my downloading is stops. Here I am talking about the torrent downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: from tomshardware
bhushan sampat: Aug 31, 2014, 5:11 AM

> 1. Go to control panel
> 2. network and sharing --> change adapter settings
> 3. right click on connected wifi network --> properties
> 4. configure --> power management
> 5. untick "allow computer to turn off this device to save power"

This worked for me. Now I can use my laptop's wifi when connected to LED with closed lid.

Comment: This only addresses the issue of the wireless adapter. The main issue is that the laptop itself goes to sleep when the lid is closed and your solution does not fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
- control panel 
  - Power option
    - select what closing the lid does.
      - change when closing the lid to Do nothing( on battery and plugged in).

Try closing the lid first, if that doesn't work you'll want to change the power option to high performance, this will help prevent the laptop from turning off devices to save power.